# How to move base canvas in FabricJS?

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm stumped on how to achieve this with FabricJS. I have the fabric container:

```
<div class="canvasContainer canvasDemo">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1935" height="1380"></canvas>
</div>
```

with the corresponding CSS:

```
.canvasContainer {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 935px;
    height: 380px;
}

#canvas {
   overflow: visible
}
```

This effectively creates a much larger canvas inside a container. I was hoping there was something built-in to Fabric that would allow me to "move" the entire canvas to different parts of the overall canvas. Basically, the goal is to have a smaller visible area on a much larger overall canvas.

My goal is to have the move icon on the visible canvas when it is in selection mode so the user can move the entire canvas to other sections of the overall drawing.

Any ideas on how to achieve this with FabricJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem. I need a hand to move to others zones of canvas and in my case, the scroll don't is an option...

Have you tried x Zoom In Zoom Out? Probably is a solution for you, please look: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3TMA/98/

```
<canvas id="c" width="1935" height="1380"></canvas>
```